# How do I make text move up the screen in a curve motion

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make my text move like shown in the picture but I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery. Can someone figure out how to make it so the text moves on scroll? Thank you.[Here's what I want to happen when scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfMQa.png)

Comment: I don’t understand what animation your picture represents. Are you saying you have a black-and-white cat icon, and you want it to move left, up, and right? Would it instantly change into text at some point during that movement? What does scrolling have to do with the animation?

Comment: The cat represents the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how you could go about making this using code, however their are several tutorials to make files do this and then you could try to embed it in your website. [link to video search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+make+text+follow+a+path+in+html+animation)

Hope you can solve your issue!

[edit] What I'm trying to say is it may be easier to do this using another program and then embedding something.